# How to disable Facebook account verification when I login from different country

Tags: facebook, security, login

As Facebook is blocked by Iranian government, we have to access it through VPNs and other proxy software (e.g. [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/)) which their servers are scattered over the world.

The problem is Facebook is alerted when I login from a "different country" and asks for the account verification.

To make the situation worse, Facebook asks to identify my tagged friends as the security check which is almost impossible to do when your friends are not tagged in photos properly. For Instance, here is a though one:

[image]

Is there any way to disable this "country security check" and/or disable photo tag identification?

Comment: you should consider posting this question on our travel website.

Answer (score 2):

It happens whenever Facebook detects 'uncommon' activity/'suspicious' activity such as logging in from a IP address located far away from the regular one.

What you can do is, log into Facebook from your own country - with the "Keep me Logged in" feature on your laptop or mobile, then travel to the other country and just open your already logged in Facebook account.

Also, if you log in from a mobile app or a mobile device, or from m.facebook.com from any Laptop/Computer, this kind of security check will not occur. - After getting logged in by this way, you can head to www.facebook.com and use the complete site.

Comment: The problem is I want to access my Facebook account from different computers and each time I use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/) to bypass the filtering, as is stated in the question, it connects to a server located in some country which is not customizable.

Comment: @Isaac Try using m.facebook.com

Comment: [m.facebook.com](http://m.facebook.com) is also blocked in Iran and I still have to use [Tor](https://www.torproject.org/). While it would be really helpful (and maybe a security breach) if this doesn't ask those security question, it still cannot replace the actual facebook.com. It would be nice if there is a some way to access facebook.com from different countries without having to ask these security questions.

Comment: @Isaac After getting logged in by this way, you can head to www.facebook.com and use the complete site.