# I change locations frequently and Facebook doesn't like it

Tags: facebook, login, location

I change my location quite frequently and every now and then Facebook prompts me to confirm the location by tagging friends’ pictures.

Are there any means to avoid these prompts, other than staying in the same place?

Comment: Not sure if m.facebook is still an option, but it might be... http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26766/how-to-disable-facebook-account-verification-when-i-login-from-different-country

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off Login Notifications/Approvals. It’s in *Account Settings* → *Security*.

Comment: They are both deactivated, still I receive those prompts.

Answer (score 0):

It happens whenever Facebook detects 'uncommon' activity/'suspicious' activity such as logging in from a IP address located far away from the regular one.

What you can do is, log into Facebook from your own country - with the "Keep me Logged in" feature on your laptop or mobile, then travel to the other country and just open your already logged in Facebook account.

Also, if you log in from a mobile app or a mobile device, or from m.facebook.com from any Laptop/Computer, this kind of security check will not occur. - After getting logged in by this way, you can head to www.facebook.com and use the complete site.